# Running a dash app from multidirectory structure

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash

I seem to have trouble running dash/(probably also flask?) apps from a multiple directory structure with python.

Basically I have a large dash app I'm writing which would be annoying to maintain if everything was in one giant "app.py" file. I'd like to have a few folders to organize types of visualizations, accessing multiple sources of data, etc. As soon as I try to break it up into multiple scripts and folders I get a weird 'No module named..." error which seems to have nothing to do with the imports.  Here is the simplest example which recreates the error:

Folder structure:

```
big_dashboard/
    __init__.py
    __main__.py
    src/
        __init__.py
        does_things/
            __init__.py
            do_a_thing.py
```

Here are the contents of __main__.py

```py
import dash
from src.does_things.do_a_thing import do

do()

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = dash.html.H1('Hello World!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True, host = 'localhost', port = 5000)
```

Here are the contents of do_a_thing.py:

```py
def do():
    print('Thing successfully did')
```

Here is what prints to the console (not even an error):

```
Thing successfully did

Dash is running on http://localhost5000/

* Serving Flask app "__main__" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
C:\...\Anaconda3\python.exe: No module named /big_dashboard
```

And the app immediately crashes. The printed message looks like an import error, but as do() works fine my relative imports seem to all function.  Even the app successfully launches.  I'm sure I'm missing something super basic and fundamental here, but that "error" doesn't give me much to go on.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In the _`_main__.py` file, for your `app.run()` you have a syntax error.

replace

```
app.run(debug=True, host='localhost, port=5000)
```

with

```
app.run(debug=True, host='localhost', port=5000)
```

check also that `do_thing.py` file is named `do_a_thing.py`.